# Average of textfields depending on how many textfield are "used"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Little explication: I have an app with 5 textfields, i already got the code to make the avaerage of them. Using floates and giving a variable to each textfield.so, the adding of the value of all the textfield /5 (divided per 5)

My problem is that when a textfield is leaved emptty, its not goona be /5, if user fill in only 4 cells it will be/4 and so on.

Question: how to divide the adding of cells depending in how many cells have content?

I was tryng with textfield.text.length > 0 in an if. But i dont get it

Thanks, hope i was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check each textfield and see if the text is NULL or blank (@"")

Use an int to keep track of the number of textfields that have a value.

For example:

```
int counter = 0;
float total = 0.0;

if([textfield1.text length] > 0)
{
    counter++;
    float thisValue = [textfield1.text floatValue];
    total = total + thisValue;
}
```

repeat this for all 5 textfields and then divide your total by the counter variable.
You could include the if statement in a loop if you are going to vary the number of text fields or to reduce the amount of coding you do.

EDIT I have changed my answer based on the good suggestions of other to use text.length

Comment: It sounds easy and practical. Thanks a lot

Comment: A much simpler statement would be: `if (textfield1.text.length) {  counter++; }`. There is no need to check for `nil`.

Comment: You can replace both of those conditions with `if ([textfield1.text length] > 0])` since if the string is `nil` (you should use `nil` instead of `NULL` by the way) it will return a length of 0.

Comment: no problems, you can also get the float value from the textfield in the if function and add it to your total

Comment: if somones is interested, `float answer = (total/counter);
    verageanswer.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", answer];`
this is the action i put to show the avereage in a label

Answer (score 0):

try to count the number of used textfields by increasing a number every time you read out a textfield that has valid text in it and divide the result by that number. (logically the "number" should be initialized as 0)

Comment: I understand, so i can do it with an if, if each textfield.length > 0, do something.

Comment: Wich with property should i make the "number" ? Thnx